# Wireshark is not display the packets between the client and server

Tags: windows-10, networking, tcp, wireshark, packet

On my machine there a **TCP server** is running @**port 54000** which is a echo server it sends the same message which is sent to it.

I have multiple clients which is connected to this server. Clients and the server are running in the same machine (not inside of Virtual Machine).

I have specified **tcp.port==54000** as the display filter to capture the packets going through the port 54000 but **Wireshark** is not display any packets.

In order to monitor the packets I selected **Wi-Fi** form the wireshark.

Server and client are running & they are communicating with each other but why the packets are not displayed by in Wireshark and How can I fix it ?

Thanks in Advance Guys!

Comment: Are your clients perhaps running on the same machine? To which IP address, exactly, are they connecting?

Comment: Are you sure you're tracing the correct adapter?

Comment: In that case, are you _very_ sure you're tracing the correct adapter? "Same machine" communications _do not_ go through the physical Ethernet or Wi-Fi interface -- regardless of what IP address they use. Recent Wireshark+Npcap (not legacy Winpcap) should show a special "loopback" adapter.

Comment: Could you please clarify "same machine"? Are either the clients or the server running as Virtual Machines?

Comment: @DevParzival Please don't answer in comments. Add the new info directly to the question so it's available and community members don't have to dig details up from comments.

Comment: @user1686 I selected my wifi card for monitoring the packets do you mean I have to select loopback  for monitoring packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These server and client, both running locally on your PC

If you did your work on Linux, Unix, *BSD, please capture on the loopback interface (lo, lo0, etc.).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139373)